# Order by latest added to database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database with different events and I want to be able to filter these events by when they were added to the database. Do I have to add a new field for this or does Firebase have some function for it?

```
var streamer = Firestore.instance.collection('events');

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: streamer.orderBy('date').snapshots(),
```

This is what I have for filtering the events on when they will occur.

EDIT:

I think you misunderstood me. I dont mean to sort the events in reversed order. I want to sort the events by the date they were added to the database. Say for example my database contains 2 events like this:

Event X, date: 21/5-19

Event Y, date 25/5-19

Now I add event Z to the db and we got this if we sort by descending:

Event Y, date 25/5-19

Event Z, date 23/5-19

Event X, date: 21/5-19

Instead I want to sort on what items were added last, so with my sorting the db would look like:

Event Z, date 23/5-19

Event Y, date 25/5-19

Event X, date: 21/5-19

Since Event Z was the latest added event to the database.

Comment: Add `descending=true` in your oderBy.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Rubens. Especially if you can add a code snippet of how the result would look in your answer. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I dont mean to sort the events in reversed order. I want to sort the events by the date they were added to the database. Say for example my database contains 2 events like this:


Event X, date: 21/5-19
Event Y, date 25/5-19



Now I add event Z to the db and we got this if we sort by descending:
Event Y, date 25/5-19
Event Z, date 23/5-19
Event X, date: 21/5-19



Instead I want to sort on what items were added last, so with my sorting the db would look like:
Event Z, date 23/5-19
Event Y, date 25/5-19
Event X, date: 21/5-19

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify the descending order in your `orderBy`.

Following code should work for you:

```js
var streamer = Firestore.instance.collection('events');

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: streamer.orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots(),
```

Comment: for newbies (me) make sure to build the index correctly in firebase, that was my error (i had the flutter code correct)